# How do I skip to a specific place in a video using XBMC?

Tags: kodi

I'm finding it increasingly irritating not being able to skip to a specific point in a video or in the iPlayer plugin. Surely there's a way to just click on a progress bar to skip to a certain position in a video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type the time you want `HH:MM` and press Enter

Comment: there's no way to just click on the time on a progress bar though?

Comment: XBMC is a HTPC software so you are not supposed to use it with a mouse. I don't think the progress bar shown in the interface is clickable.

Comment: Actually, according to the blurb on the XBMC site it's designed to be a companion not an actual HTPC: "While XBMC functions very well as a standard media player application for your computer, it has been designed to be the perfect companion for your HTPC."